How to reference default service account in cloud run
How do I reference the default service account in cloud run to access google sheets or other google APIs and services? I can't seem to find any actually clear documentation with examples, and my friend chatGPT has decided this one's also out of his league.
Here's my code where I'm trying to initialize access to the service account. The code in general aims to leverage google sheets which contains emails and SES to send emails in bulk. Ideally this should run as a service on cloud run which is what I'm trying to do here:
import os
import logging
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import boto3
import gspread
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import secretmanager
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import json

# Initialize Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='logs.log',  # Log file name
    filemode='w',         # Overwrite the log file each time
    level=logging.DEBUG,  # Log all levels of messages
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)

# Log that the application has started
logging.info('Application has started.')

def get_service_account_credentials():
    try:
        # Initialize Secret Manager client
        secret_client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
        logging.info('Secret Manager client initialized.')

        # Build the resource name of the secret version.
        # Assuming latest version; adjust if needed.
        secret_name = os.environ.get('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SECRET_NAME')
        if not secret_name:
            raise ValueError("Environment variable 'SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SECRET_NAME' not set.")

        project_id = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
        if not project_id:
            raise ValueError("Environment variable 'GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT' not set.")

        secret_version_name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_name}/versions/latest"

        # Access the secret version
        response = secret_client.access_secret_version(name=secret_version_name)
        secret_payload = response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')
        logging.info('Service account key retrieved from Secret Manager.')

        # Load the service account JSON key
        service_account_info = json.loads(secret_payload)

        # Create credentials using the service account key
        scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
            service_account_info, scopes=scopes)
        logging.info('Service account credentials created.')

        return credentials

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error retrieving service account credentials: {e}')
        raise

try:
    # Get AWS credentials from environment variables
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

    # Set up AWS SES client using environment variables for credentials
    ses_client = boto3.client(
        'ses',
        region_name='us-east-2',
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY
    )
    logging.info('AWS SES client initialized.')
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f'Error initializing AWS SES client: {e}')

try:
    # Get credentials from service account key stored in Secret Manager
    credentials = get_service_account_credentials()

    # Authorize gspread using the credentials
    gspread_client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    logging.info('Google Sheets client authorized using service account credentials.')

    # Open the Google Sheet by ID
    sheet_id = "hiding from you all"
    spreadsheet = gspread_client.open_by_key(sheet_id)
    contact_details_sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet('contactDetails')
    logging.info('Google Sheet opened successfully.')

except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f'Error setting up Google Sheets client or opening sheet: {e}')
    contact_details_sheet = None  # Ensure it's set to None if there's an error

@app.route('/send-emails', methods=['POST'])
def send_bulk_emails():
    logging.info('Received request to /send-emails endpoint.')
    try:
        if not contact_details_sheet:
            raise ValueError("Google Sheet is not initialized. Check logs for errors.")

        # Get the data from the request
        data = request.get_json()
        logging.debug(f'Request data: {data}')

        posting_id = data.get('postingId')
        ignore_statuses = [status.strip() for status in data.get('ignoreStatuses', '').split(',')]
        subject_line = data.get('subjectLine')
        body_template = data.get('body')
        send_from_email = data.get('sendFromEmail')

        logging.info(f'Parameters extracted: postingId={posting_id}, ignoreStatuses={ignore_statuses}, sendFromEmail={send_from_email}')

        # Fetch all rows from the Google Sheet
        rows = contact_details_sheet.get_all_records()
        logging.info(f'Total rows fetched from sheet: {len(rows)}')

        # Filter rows by postingId, ignoring rows where "sentRejection?" is TRUE and ignoring any in ignoreStatuses
        filtered_rows = [
            row for row in rows
            if str(row.get('postingId')) == str(posting_id)  # Match postingId
            and row.get('sentRejection?') != 'TRUE'         # Exclude already rejected
            and (not row.get('status') or row.get('status') not in ignore_statuses)  # Allow empty status, ignore only if status in ignoreStatuses
        ]
        logging.info(f'Filtered rows count: {len(filtered_rows)}')

        if not filtered_rows:
            logging.warning('No matching records found after filtering.')
            return jsonify({"status": "No matching records found."}), 200

        # Prepare and send emails
        for row in filtered_rows:
            email = row.get('email')
            name = row.get('name')
            if not email or not name:
                logging.warning(f'Missing email or name in row: {row}')
                continue

            personalized_subject = subject_line.replace("{name}", name)
            personalized_body = body_template.replace("{name}", name)

            try:
                response = ses_client.send_email(
                    Source=send_from_email,
                    Destination={'ToAddresses': [email]},
                    Message={
                        'Subject': {'Data': personalized_subject},
                        'Body': {'Text': {'Data': personalized_body}}
                    }
                )
                logging.info(f"Email sent to {email}. SES Message ID: {response['MessageId']}")

                # Update 'sentRejection?' field in Google Sheet
                row_index = rows.index(row) + 2  # Adding 2 to account for header and zero-indexing
                sent_col = contact_details_sheet.find('sentRejection?').col
                contact_details_sheet.update_cell(row_index, sent_col, 'TRUE')
                logging.info(f"Updated 'sentRejection?' for {email} at row {row_index}.")

            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error sending email to {email}: {e}")

        return jsonify({"status": "Emails processed."}), 200

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error in /send-emails endpoint: {e}')
        return jsonify({"status": "Error processing emails.", "error": str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

I've tried leveraged google auth to get the default service account credentials, and I was expecting it to properly access the sheet. The problem is that when I go to hit the endpoint I receive the following error:
{
"error": "Google Sheet is not initialized. Check logs for errors.",
"status": "Error processing emails."
}

The error you cite is your own error from the initial statements in send_build_emails so this points to your global initialization failing. Your approach is unclear but the best practice is to use the Cloud Run service's identity (whatever Service Account it was deployed using) to assign roles such as using Sheets. I recommend you try simplifying the code to focus on ensuring that you're able to authenticate calls using gspread. Often (!?) you will need to use a domain-wide delegated Service Account for this purpose.
